# What's this short film with a mysterious teddy bear?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

A man watching telly receives a package and it's a teddy bear. Doesn't think anything of it but then opens the stuffing out of the bear to find a VCR cassette tape. He plays it and there's some spooky horror. Then as he's finished watching it he goes to another room and en route a monster pulls him through the wall. It ends there.
I'm sure this was a British short film.

Comment: Can you give any more info, e.g. a possible year, any quotes from the film, description of actors/actresses, location, anything really?

Comment: Yes it is a British short film. No quotes. 2007 roughly released. Had 1 man in it watching tele until he gets a teddy (somehow) delivered or is one of his own. Randomly opens it to reveal a VHS cassette which he then plays and a beast walks through the wall and gets him. That's all I have chap

Comment: I know you've said that's all you've got, but I'm really struggling to find anything. Can you remember anything else, however insignificant? Approximate length, for example? Nationality/ethnicity/looks of actor? Production value (i.e. cheap/big budget), what the video showed, what the monster looked like? Literally any more details would help, as I've spent A LOT of time looking thus far and am coming up totally empty.

Comment: I can answer some of those questions chap. British, white, can't remember his looks, very low budget, can't remember what the video showed, monster grabs him through a wall so you don't see him as it's more for shock factor. Additional info: I saw it at the CAN film festival in Leicester. Definitely 2006 or 2007.

Comment: The festival's website is down. I've scored through literally hundreds upon hundreds of films, but I'm getting no luck. Given the obscurity of the film, your best bet is probably to contact one of the festival organisers for a list of films shown in 2006/2007.

Comment: Thanks Andrew your help is much appreciated. I knew the festival was over and I tried them with no joy unfortunately. Thanks again chap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Insides (2005) - Pic 01]

**Insides** (2005)

According to [Cambridge Cinema Short](http://cinema-shorts.org/the-strawberry-shorts-film-marquee-fordham-fest-2010-programme-10/) it's about:

> A lonely man with a dark past and the horror beneath his feet.

One [reviewer](http://www.leftlion.co.uk/articles.cfm/title/bang--short-film-festival/id/823#.UyZWLKhdxWo) noted that:

> Insides by Dan Gitsham introduced a completely contrasting genre.
>   Incredibly atmospheric, I was unsure of what to expect as the **lone
>   man wandered around his empty, cluttered house**.
>
> At the discovery of an oddly placed **video cassette inside a stuffed
>   toy** under a floor-board – having been a reluctant viewer of ‘The
>   Ring’ – I knew it was time to hide.

[image: Insides (2005) - Pic 02]

Watch it on the [director's site](http://www.dangitsham.co.uk/Insides.html) or head straight to [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/25898196).

I know you've searched long and hard for this one. Enjoy the show!

<sup>*~ Screenshots taken directly from the video*</sup>

Comment: Rumandwrite you've just made your way into my top 10 legends list and currently sit 3rd behind Gandhi and Jesus! Thanks amigo this is superb!  You've found me some great answers lately to which I'm really grateful chap.

Comment: +1: Even I love you for this. This was on the verge of getting a bounty placed on it by me as it was driving me crazy. I couldn't find anything and literally trawled through hundreds of films. Will have to watch it myself now! Thanks.